# External JS file in web user control?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, webusercontrol

In a html page we use the head tag to add reference to our external .js files .. we can also include script tags in the body .. But how do we include our external .js file in a web user control?

After little googling I got this. It works but is this the only way?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "MyUniquekey", @"<script src=""myJsFile.js"" type=""text/javascript""></script>", false);
```

-- Zuhaib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("key", "path/to/script.js");
```

That's the way I always do it anyway

Answer (score 1):

> Yes this works too .. but why does all
>   the script gets dumped in the body and
>   not in the head??

There's a potential workaround for that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/scriptregister.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of incorrect .. about needing the Javascript in the body.

A Javascript function would sit in the head unexecuted and not at all affected by the fact that elements are still to load.

Often there is a single call at the end of a page to start execution of scripts at the top.
(Other methods available)

The only reason that script gets dumped in the body, is because MS doesn't seem to give 2 hoots about JavaScript. 
Shame, because forcing us all to use .NET proper, just makes the world full of sluggish pages that needlessly run back and forth to servers for the tiniest requirmenet.